# Inconsistencies with an LP in Gurobi

Tags: python, constraints, linear-programming, gurobi, operations-research

I have the following problem. I am currently trying to solve a scheduling problem in Gurobi using Python. I am using the variable $c_{it}$ to restrict the number of shift changes from the previous day to the current day (the maximum number of changes is controlled with Nr_max). The code also does exactly that, even the shift changes are output correctly in the respective periods. For example, if $x_{122}=1$ is valid, so worker $1$ works shift $2$ on day $2$, and at the same time $x_{i33}=1$, so he completes the third shift on the following day, then the second element of the list "Changes Worker 1" =1 (the list starts only for $c_{i2}$, because the first change can happen only in period $t=2$). If I slowly increase the value for Max, then the results also remain consistent up to the point of Max = 9. There, the list "Changes Worker 1" shows nine changes (i.e. 9 entries with a 1), but if you look at the output of each shift and compare them, there are no nine changes.
How can it be that the model "adds" these changes after a certain point and how do I have to change the model so that this no longer happens?

```
I did a lot of research on the web!
```

Answer (score 0):

You only model:

```
1. sc[i,t]=0 => no change in shift
2. sum(sc) <= 9
```

If the actual number of changes is say 7, the model does not need to reflect this in sc. This is not a bug, just a property of the model. Putting it differently, sc is not the number of shift changes but only a bound on them.
So just don't report sc directly to the user. Rather report the actual number of shift changes.

If you really want to have sc contain the exact number of changes, you need to add the constraint:

```
3. sc[i,t]=1 => there was a change in shift
```

You could add sc to the objective to push it down. But be aware that this may change the model somewhat (using a very small penalty coefficient can help).

Comment: Thanks, i get it. It forces sc<=1 if there is a change which means it must take 1, but if sc<=0 i could also be 1 or 0. So i need to include an upper limit, correct? How would i do that?

Comment: I think you got that reversed.